# Kids' building blocks

Tags: clone-brands

[image: []

Found this on eBay, looks to be just 1×2 bricks with round ends, what size are they, is having just that size to restrict?

Just found link on Kiddle website, see there that there are also 1×1's & 1×3's both straight & about 45° corner.

O! not the same, having side indents.

Comment: The eBay listing would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

After a few reverse image searches, I found the same kind of building blocks at https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000201944997.html with the following diagram:

[image: dimensions of block]

i.e. a single 2x1 block is supposed to be 25mm tall, 18.5mm wide and 10mm deep.

Comment: Right, it is what they are looking for on another question 'between Lego System & Duplo'. Less than twice as long as wide. Guess not count stud height same as length.